# Convert an XML String to CSV file (Java) -> CSV Result is empty

Tags: java, xslt

I need help understanding why the XML String does not convert into a CSV file. Why is the CSV Resut always empty?

Here is an example of a Java Code

```
public class transformCSV_1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            String xmlData = new String(
                    "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><PurchaseOrder  xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"http://localhost:8080/source/schemas/poSource/xsd/purchaseOrder.xsd\"><Reference>SBELL-2002100912333601PDT</Reference><Actions><Action><User>SVOLLMAN</User></Action></Actions><Requestor>Sarah J. Bell</Requestor><User>SBELL</User><CostCenter>S30</CostCenter><ShippingInstructions><name>Sarah J. Bell</name><address>400 Oracle Parkway Redwood Shores CA 94065 USA</address><telephone>650 506 7400</telephone></ShippingInstructions><SpecialInstructions>Air Mail</SpecialInstructions><LineItems><LineItem ItemNumber=\"1\"><Description>A Night to Remember</Description><Part Id=\"715515009058\" UnitPrice=\"39.95\" Quantity=\"2\"/></LineItem><LineItem ItemNumber=\"2\"><Description>The Unbearable Lightness Of Being</Description><Part Id=\"37429140222\" UnitPrice=\"29.95\" Quantity=\"2\"/></LineItem><LineItem ItemNumber=\"3\"><Description>Sisters</Description><Part Id=\"715515011020\" UnitPrice=\"29.95\" Quantity=\"4\"/></LineItem></LineItems></PurchaseOrder>");
            String stylesheet = new String(
                    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"><xsl:output method=\"text\" /><xsl:variable name=\"delimiter\" select=\"','\" /><!-- define an array containing the fields we are interested in --><xsl:variable name=\"fieldArray\"><field>Reference</field><field>User</field><field>Reject</field><field>Requestor</field></xsl:variable><xsl:param name=\"fields\" select=\"document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='fieldArray']/*\" /><xsl:template match=\"/\"><!-- output the header row --><xsl:for-each select=\"$fields\"><xsl:if test=\"position() != 1\"><xsl:value-of select=\"$delimiter\"/></xsl:if><xsl:value-of select=\".\" /></xsl:for-each><!-- output newline --><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select=\"PurchaseOrder\"/></xsl:template><xsl:template match=\"PurchaseOrder\"><xsl:variable name=\"currNode\" select=\".\" /><!-- output the data row --><!-- loop over the field names and find the value of each one in the xml --><xsl:for-each select=\"$fields\"><xsl:if test=\"position() != 1\"><xsl:value-of select=\"$delimiter\"/></xsl:if><xsl:value-of select=\"$currNode/*[name() = current()]\" /></xsl:for-each><!-- output newline --><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>");

            InputStream xmlSource = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    xmlData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            InputStream styleSource = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    stylesheet.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

            StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(styleSource);
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
                    .newTransformer(stylesource);
            Source source = new DOMSource(document);
            Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("src/resultI.csv"));
            transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Best way is to use XSLT to "transform" the XML to CSV --> Can someone give me hint?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XML and XSLT separately, rather than burying them away in the Java code, which makes it hard to read. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to load the XSLT code from a file or URI (instead of from a string) as otherwise your approach of doing `<xsl:param name="fields" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='fieldArray']/*" />` where `document('')` tries to pull in the XSLT code again is likely to fail, unless you set up a special resolver.